# Adding a ferrite bead to source of mosfet (smps)

Tags: mosfet, inductance, emi-filtering, ferrite-bead

We are designing a SMPS (ultra low noise) based on TI schematics http://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidrgc2/tidrgc2.pdf (5V, 15W quasi resonant)

In order to reduce EMI (we have some ringing across Mosfet when its turned off) we added some ferrite beads before the R4 and R5. (330 mA, 600R/100MHz, 480mOhm DCR)

Of course we modified the R4 and R5 (we subtracted the R of the ferrite bead). We also added a FB on gate of mosfet (same specs).

However while ringing decreased substantially , every time we push to 15W (load) our unit goes bad. It works fine at 5 W.

I read that inductance on the mosfet source is a bad thinng in SMPS. Can it be the root cause (inductance of the FB)? Am I missing something?

**update:**
We removed the ferrite beads as instructed. Will try a different approach.

Comment: You normally keep smps power paths (especially the switching node) short to avoid parasitic inductances. How does a inductor behave when you suddenly Interrupt the current path? RC snubber is the thing your looking for.

Comment: That's what you pay with for introducing L. Please show oscillograms. Listen to Jogitech! RC is underestimated for some snubbing applications.

Comment: Because you mentioned ultra low noise...slower fet transitions (adding more gate resistance) have a positive effect on ringing emi (on the expense of more switching losses)

Comment: I did add a RC snubber but we changed the Mosfet to http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/52/57/bd/6a/e6/fb/41/ff/DM00116135.pdf/files/DM00116135.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00116135.pdf. RC snubber is 47pf/50R but that does not reduce the ringing significantly . When increased to 330pf/50R Mosfet goes bad

Comment: Yeap I have a 50R on gate + FB

Comment: How much voltage margin do you have?

Comment: With the 47pf/50R RC snubber we get ringing up to 590V. reading the http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slpa010/slpa010.pdf we chose the C 3x C parasitic of mosfet (18pf) = 47pf

Comment: Please note that on Quasiresonant smps , the ringing happens when Mosfet is turned off and demagnetization happens.We have the RDC network in place (and it helped bringing it down from 700V to 590V. Still thats too much , we want it under 500v

Comment: Have you considered going for a design that operates CCM. I'm unsure where your ringing is so can't advise any more but do please post a picture of the waveform.

Comment: EMI is all about dI/dt and area of loop.  Can you reduce radiated loop area instead? and use low Q snubbers  also note Design is improved with synchronous rectifiers instead of diode.  https://webench.ti.com/webench5/power/webench5.cgi?origin=ODS__UCC28740&VinMin=90.00&VinMax=265.00&O1V=5.00&O1I=3&base_pn=UCC28740&AppType=AC&Flavor=UCC24636&isolated=Y&Topology=Flyback&op_TA=30&source=AC&line_fsw=60&optfactor=3&lang_chosen=en_US

Comment: from what i have read you could add the ferrite at the gate  , lower the switching speed if possible , or use better layout , use TVS diodes at lower mosfet D-S ...