# RC snubber on Mosfet (smps) max C

Tags: mosfet, nmos, snubber, emi-filtering

I am designing a SMPS from TI http://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidrgc2/tidrgc2.pdf

We replaced the Mosfet fro schematic with STL11N65M5 that has a Coss of 18pf

So I am designing a RC snubber across it and I calculated at about 47pf (and use R of 50R). The overshoot and damping is not optimized.

So I am trying to increase the C to 330pf (with a 50R) but my Mosfet blows up. How to calculate the maximum capacitance of RC snubber that Mosfet can whitstand ? Is it in relation to C and R ?

(we already removed the ferrite beads question)

Comment: Please use your existing question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/369428/adding-a-ferrite-bead-to-source-of-mosfet-smps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a ferrite bead to source of mosfet (smps)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/369428/adding-a-ferrite-bead-to-source-of-mosfet-smps)

Comment: The 2 questions relate to same product but are diffrent. One is asking about ferrite beads (and I will close it). Please allow this question to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that 0.1uF to 1000pf are good choices